# How to play shoutcast radio in C# UWP application?

Tags: c#, uwp, streaming, shoutcast, internet-radio

I have UWP(Universal Windows Platform) Application and I want to add shoutcast player, but can't find anything how to do that.

I have Button  which should start/stop playing music and volume slider.
I found element in xaml such as MediaElement but when I'm trying to use it like that:

```
private async void StartPlayer()
        {
            var result = await AdaptiveMediaSource.CreateFromUriAsync(new Uri("http://camon22.sxcore.net:"+Port, UriKind.Absolute));
            if (result.Status == AdaptiveMediaSourceCreationStatus.Success)
            {
                var astream = result.MediaSource;
                Media.SetMediaStreamSource(astream);
            }
            else
            {
                var dialog = new MessageDialog("Result Status Wrong!\n"+result.Status);
                await dialog.ShowAsync();
            }
        }
```

I got `UnsupportedManifestContestType` Status.

Anybody knows how to play radio in UWP application?

Comment: I know it's too late but hope my answer could help you. :)